# How to take textbox value from an asp.net form to a classes in vb.net code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new in Vb.net and try to learn how to program,but i stuck on this stages.

I create a new sub and declare it in 1 form

```
Public Class WebForm5
    Public Sub info()
        Dim x As String
        Dim y As String
        Dim z As String
        x = txtbookn.Text
        y = txtqua.Text.ToString
        z = txtpri.Text.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```

and i try to pass it to another classes which in

```
Public Class Product
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Book_Name = (value for x)
        Me.UnitPrice =(value for y)
        Me.quantty=(value for z)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it in the constructor

```
Public Class Product
   Public Sub New(x as String, y as String, z As String)
      Me.Book_Name = x
      Me.UnitPrice = y
      Me.quantty = z
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then in your page you can call it as

```
Dim MyProduct as Product = New Product(txtbookn.Text, txtqua.Text, txtpri.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your x, y, and z variables are not in the scope of the `New()` sub. If you want them to be accessible you either have to pass them as parameters, or they need to be defined outside of both classes. Right now they only exist in `info()`.

Comment: May i know how can i defined outside both of the classes, i'm new, wanna learn more.

Comment: Sorry I meant outside of the methods. They still need to be in your scope. If you maintain 2 classes you'll need to pass them as parameters when you call your method.